# BigQuery - fetch 1000000 records and do some process over data using goLang

Tags: database, go, google-bigquery

I Have 1000000 records inside BigQuery. what is the best way to fetch data from DB and process using goLang? I'm getting timeout issue if fetch all the data without limit. already I increase the limit to 5min, but it takes more than 5 min. 
I want to do some streaming call or pagination implementation, But i don't know in golang how I do.

```
var FetchCustomerRecords = func(req *http.Request) *bigquery.RowIterator {
    ctx := appengine.NewContext(req)
    ctxWithDeadline, _ := context.WithTimeout(ctx, 5*time.Minute)
    log.Infof(ctx, "Fetch Customer records from BigQuery")
    client, err := bigquery.NewClient(ctxWithDeadline, "ddddd-crm")
    q := client.Query(
        "SELECT * FROM Something")

    q.Location = "US"
    job, err := q.Run(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Infof(ctx, "%v", err)
    }
    status, err := job.Wait(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Infof(ctx, "%v", err)

    }
    if err := status.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Infof(ctx, "%v", err)
    }
    it, err := job.Read(ctx)

    if err != nil {
        log.Infof(ctx, "%v", err)
    }
    return it
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the table contents directly without issuing a query.  This doesn't incur query charges, and provides the same row iterator as you would get from a query.

For small results, this is fine.  For large tables, I would suggest checking out the new [storage api](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage/), and the code sample on the [samples page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage/samples).

For a small table or simply reading a small subset of rows, you can do something like this (reads up to 10k rows from one of the public dataset tables):

```
func TestTableRead(t *testing.T) {
    ctx := context.Background()
    client, err := bigquery.NewClient(ctx, "my-project-id")
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }

    table := client.DatasetInProject("bigquery-public-data", "stackoverflow").Table("badges")
    it := table.Read(ctx)

    rowLimit := 10000
    var rowsRead int
    for {
        var row []bigquery.Value
        err := it.Next(&row)
        if err == iterator.Done || rowsRead >= rowLimit {
            break
        }

        if err != nil {
            t.Fatalf("error reading row offset %d: %v", rowsRead, err)
        }
        rowsRead++
        fmt.Println(row)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can split your query to get 10x of 100000 records and run in multiple goroutine

use sql query like
 `select * from somewhere order by id DESC limit 100000 offset 0`

and in next goroutine `select * from somewhere order by id DESC limit 100000 offset 100000`